# Port Forwarding on Router via SSH

Tags: macos, ssh, router, port-forwarding

I want to forward 3 ports on my router to a machine with a local IP of 192.168.0.14, via SSH (in the Mac OS X Terminal). If I were to do it manually from my router's preference page it would look like [this](http://postimg.org/image/czy2qeh97/).

My router's local IP is 192.168.0.1. What command or commands would I need to use? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this depends on your router and if it can even accept commands via an SSH session (Cisco/businessclass and the like). What is the model of your router?

Comment: @Abraxas Cisco DPC3825

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The guide for your model (http://www.cisco.com/web/consumer/support/userguides2/4021196_B.pdf) does not appear to indicate that your router supports command-line management. It appears to be done from the Web Interface only.